# how do you specify the wipeIn direction in dojo

Tags: animation, dojo, effects

How do you change the direction of wipeIn?
This example wipes in from top.  How would I make it wipe in from bottom, from left or from right?

```
require(["dojo/fx", "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-style", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"],
function(coreFx, dom, style, on){
  on(dom.byId("basicWipeButton"), "click", function(){
    style.set("basicWipeNode", "display", "none");
    coreFx.wipeIn({
      node: "basicWipeNode"
    }).play();
  });
});

<button type="button" id="basicWipeButton">Wipe It In!</button>
<div id="basicWipeNode" style="width: 200px; background-color: red; display: none;">
  <b>This is a container of random content to wipe in!</b>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at the [Rotator](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/widget/rotator/Wipe.html) widget, which has the wipe direction. Hope it meets your need.

Comment: I saw that.  Except that the example seems to do everything I need.  It's simple, yet I can't figure out how to get it to wipe in an alternate direction.  you'd think it would be a simple option.